# Is there an easy way in BizTalk 2006 R2 to view the XML sent out a SOAP send port?

Tags: soap, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

Seems like I should be able to get at it through HAT or something like that, but I can't seem to find where this would be at. Basically I have a business partner who is asking me to send the XML I am sending them for troubleshooting purposes. Any ideas? Seems like this should be a no brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  HAT is the answer.  But to get to the message in HAT you need to turn on message tracking in the Send Port.  By default, the message bodies are not tracked.  If he wants to see what is sent to him as SOAP, be sure to track the message body after the pipeline processing.

To get the message in HAT, locate the message instance and tell it to Save Tracked Messages via a Right-Click on the item.  It will give you some privacy warnings and then prompt you for a location to save the message.  The saved message(s) will consist of an .out file with the message body and a .xml file with context data.